# How can I convert JSON format text to dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, pyspark

I am trying to convert below JSON format text to pandas or spark data frame, but it is giving below error.

> ERROR:  JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Python CODE:

```
# import pandas to read json file
import json
path = "sample.json"
with open(path, 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
    data = data.replace('\t','')
    data = data.replace('\n','')
    data = data.replace(',}','}')
    data = data.replace(',]',']')
obj = json.loads(data)
```

JSON file format

[image]

Output of data after reading .json file by using open function

[image]

How can I convert above text as a data frame?

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as properly formatted text. That said, what you do is NOT the way to process JSON. There is `json` module in standard library, but for pandas check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Like the error message says, that's not valid JSON. The trivial solution is to fix the input manually. You are already doing some manual fixups before evaluating it; do some more.

Comment: Note that first opening and last closing curly brackets (braces) should  be square brackets instead. The inner braces should not be replaced,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got, I added few lines of code

```
path = "sample.json"
with open(path, 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
    data = data.replace('\t','')
    data = data.replace('\n','')
    data = data.replace(',}','}')
    data = data.replace(',]',']')
data = data.replace("null", "''")
liss = []
data1 = data[1:-1]
data2 = data1.split("},")
for i in data2:
  last_value = i[len(i)-1]
  if last_value != "}":
    new_text = i+"}"
    liss.append(new_text)
  else:
    new_text = i
    liss.append(new_text)
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":liss})

sample_df["Col1"] = sample_df["Col1"].apply(lambda x : dict(eval(x)) )
df3 = sample_df["Col1"].apply(pd.Series )
df3
```

Comment: The proper fix is probably to repair whatever produced this broken pretend-JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read the json and save it in a dictionary.
Once you have this dictionary you can create a spark dataframe with the following line of code

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(dict)
```